# Compare columns from SUM(CASE...END) in the same query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to add a column named `Ready` to my query that checks if the sum of `Complete` is = to the sum of `Total` and places 'Y' if True and 'N' if FALSE.

Here is my query that works producing 4 columns

```
 SELECT pc.Sub,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `SheetStatus` LIKE 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Complete',
    SUM(CASE WHEN `SheetStatus` LIKE 'Not started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Not Started',
    SUM(CASE WHEN `CheckSheet` LIKE '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total'        
FROM `pc`
Group By pc.Sub WITH ROLLUP
```

I just cant figure out how to create the extra column if it is possible at all.
Regards

Comment: so you are trying to alter the table based on a condition? Why the heck would you want to do that?

Comment: @75inchpianist He wants to add a fifth column to the select that is computed from two other columns in his select.

Comment: Have you tried something like `CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN \`SheetStatus\` LIKE 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = SUM(CASE WHEN \`CheckSheet\` LIKE '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'Y' else 'N' as 'Ready'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT pc.Sub,
    SUM(IF(`SheetStatus`='Complete',1,0) AS 'Complete',
    SUM(IF(`SheetStatus`='Not started',1,0) AS 'Not Started',
    SUM(IF(`CheckSheet` LIKE '%',1,0) AS 'Total'
    IF(SUM(IF(`CheckSheet` LIKE '%',1,0) = SUM(IF(`SheetStatus`='Complete',1,0),"Y","N") AS Ready
FROM `pc`
Group By pc.Sub WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 1):

Try outer SELECT

```
SELECT `Complete`, 
       `Not Started`, 
       `Total`, 
       CASE WHEN `Complete` = `Total` THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END `Ready`
  FROM (
SELECT pc.Sub,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `SheetStatus` LIKE 'Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Complete`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `SheetStatus` LIKE 'Not started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Not Started`,
    SUM(CASE WHEN `CheckSheet` LIKE '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `Total`        
FROM `pc`
GROUP BY pc.Sub WITH ROLLUP) t
```

Comment: Amazing just what I was needing, thanks so much peterm, this was my first post to the Stack